# "There were only X and Y" or "There was only X and Y"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What's the correct construction and why?

Example sentence:

> Since there **was/were** only a couple and two families, she had the freedom to choose her seat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does *a couple and two families* sound like something that's more than one? It certainly does to my ears. *Only* there is just an adverb and has no effect whatsoever on the grammatical number of the phrase *a couple and two families* which is the subject of that clause. And since the subject is a plural thing, you should use *were* to make the copula verb of the clause match up the subject in number. Yes, with constructions like *there is/are* or *there was/were*, the subject comes after the verb and not before it as is typically the case in English. When *there* is used like that, it's called [**a syntactic expletive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive):

> A syntactic expletive is a word that performs a syntactic role but contributes nothing to meaning.

In general, the usage pattern for the expletive pronoun *there* looks like this:

```
there is/was [singular subject]

there are/were [plural subject]
```

Examples:

> There were **a boy and two adults** in the room.
>
> There are **an apple and a cup of tea** on the table.

However, note that in everyday spoken English, while grammatically wrong, native English speakers many times would use the singular *there is/was* even in situations when the subject is plural. For example: *"There was 30,000 people at the concert"*, *There's two people waiting for you in the lobby.* This is so common that using *there is/was* with a subject that's plural is basically considered the norm in conversational English. Why that happens has probably something to do with he fact that *there's* and *there was* are phonetically faster and easier to say than *there are* and *there were*. But that's just my guess.

Comment: "There are an apple and a cup of tea on the table" sounds VERY wrong to me (native). I know it technically *should* be correct, since I'd say "An apple and a cup of tea are on the table," but it still sounds incredibly unnatural to use "there are." Using the singular may be taking over, I think.

Comment: Well, that was the point that I was trying to make at the very end of my answer. *There's* is common that you'll hardly ever hear people use its plural counterpart *there are*. Like it or hate it, that's the reality of it.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm not disagreeing! Just adding my own experience to emphasize how common using "there is/was" for plurals really is.