# There was a bed, a desk and two windows. Could it be "there were" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

There was a bed, a desk and two windows in my room.

Could it be "there were" in the sentence Above?

Comment: In most such examples, depending on whether the elements are viewed individually or as a group (or parts of a whole), both singular and plural are possible. Thus **there was peaches and cream for dessert** and **there were peaches and apples on the plate**  In your example, the singular sounds more natural but the plural is possible.

Comment: Compare [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317302/why-do-we-use-was-not-were-here-there-was-a-lot-of-wind-and-heavy-rain) about "there was/were wind and rain", [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159399/there-were-only-x-and-y-or-there-was-only-x-and-y) about "there was/were only X and Y", and several other questions.